# MVC and class diagrams

Tags: model-view-controller, class-diagram

I have done some programming with MVC but never really thought about class diagrams within them, but thinking about it I dont understand how a class diagram would work with one.

Would you just create a class diagram of each model,

Also, when I have used codenigter, i return query results from the model rather than a whole object, so would there even be any attributes?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Would you just create a class diagram of each model

Anything that helps with clarity. I find its easiest to create a new diagram for each model.

> Also, when I have used codenigter, i return query results from the model rather than a whole object, so would there even be any attributes?

Im not sure what you mean here? Why do you think your "results" are not objects? In pure OO everything (Integers, Strings etc) are objects too.